# what kind of speech of part does OFF stand for in the following sentence?

Tags: american-english

(This song is a rip off to DEA LEPPARD "pour some sugar on me")  it's actually a random comment i saw under a music video. And i still don't get both meaning and grammar..

Comment: Verb+preposition phrase "to rip off" is among many (to pick up, to clean up) that can be used as a noun, I think.

Comment: A "[rip off](http://thefreedictionary.com/rip+off)" is when you take something belonging to someone else, change it just a little bit, and call it yours.

Answer (score 1):

*Rip off* is a 1960s slang phrasal verb which can mean either "steal [something from somebody]" or "rob [somebody of something":

> He built bookcases with cinderblocks and boards he ripped off from a construction site.
>
> Eighty bucks for an oil change. Those bastards really ripped me off.

The noun is usually spelled ‹ripoff›:

> I scored tickets, but it was a real ripoff.

Your commenter is accusing the artist of plagiarizing a Def Leppard song.